# Why am I getting math domain error when using asin, acos and atan?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
import math
def SOH(oppositeSOH, hypotenuseSOH):
    oppDIVhyp = oppositeSOH / hypotenuseSOH
    soh = math.asin(oppDIVhyp)
    print("The angle theta is equivelent to", soh)

def CAH(adjacentCAH, hypotenuseCAH):
    adjDIVhyp = adjacentCAH / hypotenuseCAH
    cah = math.acos(adjDIVhyp)
    print("Angle theta is equivelent to", cah)

def TOA(oppositeTOA, adjacentTOA):
    oppDIVhyp = oppositeTOA / adjacentTOA
    toa = math.atan(oppDIVadj)
    print("Angle theta is equivelent to", toa)

SOHCAHTOA = input("Do you want to calculate angle theta with a: soh, b:     cah, c: toh ")
A = SOHCAHTOA.upper()
if A == 'A':
    oppositeSOH = int(input("Enter the length of the opposite side "))
    hypotenuseSOH = int(input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse "))
    SOH(oppositeSOH, hypotenuseSOH)

if A == 'B':
    adjacentCAH = int(input("Enter the length of the adjacent side "))
    hypotenuseCAH = int(input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse "))
    CAH(adjacentSOH, hypotenuseSOH)

if A == 'C':
    oppositeCAH = int(input("Enter the length of the opposite side "))
    adjacentCAH = int(input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse "))
    TOA(oppositeSOH, adjacentSOH)
```

When I put 'oppDIVhyp', 'adjDIVhyp', or 'oppDIVhyp' in math.a[sin, cos or tan], its a math domain error I get in return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\sohcahtoa.py", line 23, in <module>
      SOH(oppositeSOH, hypotenuseSOH)
    File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\sohcahtoa.py", line 5, in SOH
      soh = math.asin(oppDIVhyp)
ValueError: math domain error
```

What does the math domain error mean?

Comment: What values are you/the user entering when you get those errors? It might just be that you're entering values that are impossible to calculate. An adj that's longer than a hyp or something like that.

Comment: Probably cause you're using variables you haven't given values to. (Let's say you pick "B". You set \*CAH, but then *use* \*SOH.)

Comment: Just realised and edited that

Comment: Because `oppDIVhyp` is probably not in [-1,1]...

Comment: Thanks mypetlion that was the problem m8

Comment: @AlexBarnett If you want him to see your comment, put @ before the name to notify him.

Comment: @Barmar I saw it.

Comment: @mypetlion He should still learn the proper way to use SO.

Comment: @mypetlion: As your comment answered the question, I suggest you re-post it as an answer.

Comment: @MvG Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValueError: math domain error` is produced when a function is being asked to calculate a value using parameters that don't make sense for the calculation. If you ask for the log of a negative number, for example. In this case, I'd bet that the user is entering values that are impossible for a right triangle. A hypotenuse that's shorter than one of the other two sides for example.